# iPhone is not discovering available devices in Bluetooth settings in iOS9

Tags: bluetooth, iphone, ios

I have the following devices with me:
iPhone 6 (iOS 9.2),
iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 9.2),
iPhone 6s (iOS 9.2), 
iPhone  5c (iOS 9.0.2), 
iPod Touch (iOS 8.3), 
iPhone 6 (iOS 8.4.1), 
and MacBook Pro(OS X El Capitan 10.11.1).

I have turned on Bluetooth in all devices(including MacBook Pro) in parallel, none of them are showing the other devices except iPod Touch (iOS 8.3) is showing MacBook Pro and MacBook Pro is showing all other devices.

I expected every device should display all other devices in the bluetooth section in the following picture. It's not working for some reason, but it's showing some other unknown device.

[image]

Is it the expected behaviour of the iOS devices in the latest iOS versions? or Am I missing something? or Is it a bug in iOS9?.
I reset the settings in the all devices, rebooted and turned on & off bluetooth multiple times, but I found no result.

Is anyone facing the same scenario?
How it is working in your devices?
Please share your experience and thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: Are the other devices set to be Discoverable - i.e., on the same prefs screen as that one?

Comment: Yes. In all devices it's showing as "Now discoverable as 'XXXX'".

Answer (score 1):

If you follow central - peripheral concept, then one device should start advertise service and and another device should start scan for same service.
Then it will show as discovered.

Comment: central - peripheral concept? How can I do it in the devices explicitly? Generally, users will blindly turn on bluetooth switch and expect the device to be discoverable & lazy to follow more technical guidelines to achieve a basic thing!!!

Comment: All the device doesn't show for pairing, reason didn't realize yet. But if you need to use those device  for any app then you need to scan those device by an UUID.

Comment: Okay, Just paired list is enough for me, do you have any idea which UUID I need to use for this. See my query http://stackoverflow.com/q/34592179/1996294